# Asp.net bundling breaks jquery UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, bundling-and-minification

When I publish my app in release mode, datepickers stop working.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the bunbling but I can't figure out what

Jquery and Jquery UI are both loaded in the correct order and only once.

Also `$.ui` is initialized.

if I try to bind a datepicker in the google chrome console with

```
$("#birthdate").datepicker();
```

There's no error, but the datepicker is not binded and theres no `hasDatepicker` class on the input

if I try

```
$("#birthdate").datepicker("show");
```

I have the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

because the datepicker is not initialized

Here's the code

```
<input class="form-control default-date-picker" data-msg-date="The field Birth Date must be a date." data-msg-required="The Birth Date field is required." data-rule-date="true" data-rule-required="true" id="birthdate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM" aria-required="true">

<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(function () {
          $("#birthdate").datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

I can't figure out the problem

EDIT

I noticed that I never hit a breakpoint in those jquery functions when I'm in release mode

```
/* Attach the date picker to a jQuery selection.
     * @param  target   element - the target input field or division or span
     * @param  settings  object - the new settings to use for this date picker instance (anonymous)
     */
    _attachDatepicker: function(target, settings) {
        var nodeName, inline, inst;
        nodeName = target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        inline = (nodeName === "div" || nodeName === "span");
        if (!target.id) {
            this.uuid += 1;
            target.id = "dp" + this.uuid;
        }
        inst = this._newInst($(target), inline);
        inst.settings = $.extend({}, settings || {});
        if (nodeName === "input") {
            this._connectDatepicker(target, inst);
        } else if (inline) {
            this._inlineDatepicker(target, inst);
        }
    },
/* Attach the date picker to an input field. */
    _connectDatepicker: function(target, inst) {
        var input = $(target);
        inst.append = $([]);
        inst.trigger = $([]);
        if (input.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
            return;
        }
        this._attachments(input, inst);
        input.addClass(this.markerClassName).keydown(this._doKeyDown).
            keypress(this._doKeyPress).keyup(this._doKeyUp);
        this._autoSize(inst);
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
        //If disabled option is true, disable the datepicker once it has been attached to the input (see ticket #5665)
        if( inst.settings.disabled ) {
            this._disableDatepicker( target );
        }
    },
```

Bundle code

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));


 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js"));
```

the scripts are rendered in the `<head>` section in _layout.cs

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Comment: Maybe `<script type='text/javascript'>$(function(){ //your code });</script>`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that in my question. My code is already inside a script tag. Thank you

Comment: Here's how to debug this: Press F12 in the browser and open the network tab, recreate the error and then click on the downloaded file list in the browser.  If you see JQuery downloaded then click on the console tab and verify the console is not throwing an error.  Post back to us telling us what you see and we'll go from there.  One of the maddening things about Jquery and MVC is that MVC projects load a specific release of JQuery and Javascript by default, if you ever used NUGET to getsomething there's a chance there's a release conflict.  You also don't want to bundle min files.

Comment: As I mentioned, there's no error in the console and I there's no .min in my bundles. I really can't figure out the problem. It's only when <compilation debug="False"> that I have this problem. And jquery and jquery ui are loaded because $.ui returns something. Thank you

Comment: Can you post your bundle code?  And where in the page are you calling Scripts.Render() (top or bottom)?

Comment: @mmillican My question is updated. It's weird because I can hit code in both javascript files... I don't know what's wrong with the datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This always happened to me. I'm not sure if this is the same thing.

Make sure the code below is not executed twice or search the string for duplicate @Script.Render within your Razor Page.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I checked at least 5 times for any file loaded twice and I can't find any. thank you

Comment: Nope check if @Scripts.Render is both at the top and bottom of  your Views.

Comment: Thank you. With your answer I did some cleaning in my bundles and I noticed there was an old fuelux js file. I used to use fuelux for my datepicker, so this file was probably in conflict with jquery ui.

Comment: Glad to help. I've been on stackoverflow for a while now for my own problem with dictionary and ran across your question. cheers